# Hide keyboard when Entry gets focus

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

### Situation

I have an Android app that uses an external keyboard and want to hide the soft keyboard when an `Entry` control gets focus.

### Reference

Following [this android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) it states the following:

> **Note**: If the user's device has an attached hardware keyboard, the soft input method does not appear.

However, in some Android devices, when the `Entry` gets focus the soft input *does appear*.

How can I get to hide in those cases the soft input?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the softkeyboard with this code

```
  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Get an instance of your EditText

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

To prevent the Default SoftKeyboard from appear in the EditText, override the following events

// Make the custom keyboard appear

```
    edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) showCustomKeyboard(v);
            else hideCustomKeyboard();
        }
    });
    edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCustomKeyboard(v);
        }
    });
    edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
            int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
            edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
            edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
            edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
            return true; // Consume touch event
        }
    });
}
public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
    keyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    keyboardView.setEnabled(false);
}
public void showCustomKeyboard( View v) {
    keyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    keyboardView.setEnabled(true);
    if( v!=null ){
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
    return keyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if( isCustomKeyboardVisible() ) hideCustomKeyboard(); else this.finish();
}
```

Disclaimer:- I have implemented custom keyboard in my app and I wrote this tutorial - http://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-an-android-custom-keyboard-application/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
public static void DisableSoftKeyboard (EditText editText)
{
    ((InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService)).HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, 0);
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Honeycomb) {
        editText.SetRawInputType (InputTypes.ClassText);
        editText.SetTextIsSelectable (true);
    } else {
        editText.SetRawInputType (InputTypes.Null);
        editText.Focusable = true;
    }
}
```

Implementation :

```
editText.FocusChange+= (sender, e) => {
    DisableSoftKeyboard(editText);
};
```